# Pandas - DataFrame - iOS Numbers file - iCloud

Tags: python, ios, pandas, dataframe, icloud

I am relatively new to Pandas and I've been working on Excel, csv files on-prem. I am now stuck with a use case, where I will have to read a **iOS Numbers** file which is in **iCloud** and import into a **Pandas DataFrame**. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps share an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Each `.numbers` file is a Zip archive. The actual data is stored in `.iwa` files that no one knows the format of. Numbers are not popular enough for the community to reverse engineer. I have found no Python library that could read Numbers format yet.